# Creating new gui components with win32 API

Tags: winapi, win32gui

everybody,
can you tell me is there any ways to create new gui controls(for example accordion bar, etc) in win32 api. Please if you know tell me books or links for reading.
Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, every "window" is a drawable object and you can use GDI to draw there whatever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own "controls" by registering your own window classes, and supplying a custom `WindowProc` for that class which handles the drawing, and user interaction, and constituant controls (if any). If you want to make these available to different projects, you can add them to a DLL with an `Init` function that the app calls before creating a window of your own class.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff657751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be the best place to start to get an understanding.

Depending on the intended use, there are also options to use ATL, MFC, .NET, QT or other framework, but most of them are simply wrappers around the above method.

Comment: @MikeKwan: Yes, the `WindowProc` supplied as the default (See `WNDCLASS.lpfnWndProc`)

Comment: I was just questioning your choice of the term 'default'. Of course, the default WndProc means something entirely different.

Comment: Sorry :) I forgot the exact structure when I first wrote the answer so wrote it in a semi ambigious way, allowing me to blag it either way :p